# How to make sure the data is indeed tunneled?

Tags: tunneling

I am not of the IS field so sorry if anything I write here seems pathetic.

### Background for this question:

I login to my server with the following command. The second `-L` porition is to encrypt data transition through my PC's port 2222, into port-80 dependent software in the server (for example, CMSs like Drupal or DBMSs like PHPmyadmin).

```
ssh user@1.1.1.1 -L 22:localhost:22 -L 2222:localhost:80 -i ~/.ssh/key
```

### My question:

How could I **make sure beyond any doubt**, that the second tunneling (i.e of port 80), also takes place and is successful?

Comment: give a shot to "lsof -i -n -P | grep ^ssh " , it will list port number instead of names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that a tunnel is created successfully you can run

```
lsof -i tcp | grep ^ssh
```

In the output look for your foreign address 1.1.1.1 , look at the chain formed there should be two linking entries

Comment: `lsof -i -n -P | grep ^ssh` shows only port 22. Port 80 doesn't appear. It seems the port 80 tunneling doesn't take place.

Comment: @Benia While you might be correct (I have no idea), please do not make edits that change the meaning of answers unless the OP agrees with you. So either get the OP to do the edit by themself, or ask if it would be an OK edit in comments.

Comment: Hi, you can see above in the question comment that amarnath later added this phrasing `lsof -i -n -P | grep ^ssh`. It's best to use that one. I hope amarnath will agree.